# Send value from jsp to jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I tried to sent value of input from login.jsp to `sentUser.jsp`,

I see many solutions but the problem is every solution pass `sentUser.jsp` as action in form of `login.jsp`.

And in my case, I used action for validating data and I can't remove it.

Please, I need solution. just I want to get the value of username to another JSP or in java function.

this `login.jsp`:

````
 <form class="/servletLogin" method="post" onSubmit="return validate();"
                        action="http://erpteskjgo01.join.gov.jo:5436/mjn/server/auth_save_click" id="LoginForm">

                        <h3 class="loginTitle">login</h3>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                           <div class=" form-group">
                              <label for="Username">username</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control focus" maxlength="50" placeholder="username"
                                 data-val="true" data-val-required="please enter username" id="username"
                                 name="username" />
                              <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Username"
                                 data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                           </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                           <div class=" form-group">
                              <label for="Password">password</label>
                              <input type="password" class="form-control focus" maxlength="50" placeholder="password"
                                 data-val="true" data-val-required="please enter password" id="password"
                                 name="password" />
                              <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password"
                                 data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                           </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                           <a id="link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servletLogin" style="visibility: hidden; color: red;">can't login?</a>
                        </div>
                        <label id="mylocation"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padd0">
                           <span class="sperator"></span>
                           <input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="=reqId>">

                           <button class=" searchBtn" name="button" value="login">enter</button>

                        </div>

                     </form>```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

and this page i want to get the value in it sentUser.jsp

```   <body>
                              <% String u1 = request.getParameter("username");
                                System.out.print("Heloooooo"+u1);%>

  <form action="servletLogin">
  <p>please try again</p>
  </form>
  </body>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java-backend to pass the required value via a Rest-endpoint.
Retrieve this value using the c:url tag in JSF:

```
<c:url value="pathToValue?jsfVariableName=${backendLoginVariable}" />
```

Now the variable `jsfVariableName` contains the requested login-info.

```
<a href="<c:out value="${backendLoginVariable}"/>">get-variable-value</a>
```

Should work.

Comment: Can you please explain more? i don't understand where exactly put this  <c:url value="pathToValue?jsfVariableName=${backendLoginVariable}" /> and how to get it in java ?

Comment: See my extended solution.

Comment: can i do this in JSP ?

Comment: Yes - is JSP. You can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by using `setAttribute(..)` method. Just do the following.

In `first.jsp`

> `request.setAttribute("key", value);`

In `second.jsp`

> `Object val = request.getAttribute("key");`

But remember you have to include the `second.jsp` from `first.jsp`

In `first.jsp`

```
<jsp:include page="./second.jsp">

</jsp:include>
```

Bonus: You can also set parameter while inlcuding `second.jsp`

In `first.jsp`

```
<jsp:include page="./second.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="key" value="value_from_first_jsp"/>
</jsp:include>
```

In `second.jsp`

```
String value = request.getParameter("key")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but please where exactly i should put request.setAttribute("key", value); please review my code above

Comment: In `*.jsp` file use <% ...% > tag, Inside this tag we can write your java code.

`<div>
    <%
        request.getParameter("key");
    %>
</div>`

Comment: <jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sentUser.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="key" value="username"/>
</jsp:include>

i put it under the input tag and its null

Comment: Then try to use it under `div` tag, although I think there is notning wrong in `input` tag. No need to use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` insteed just use `<jsp:include page="../../sentUser.jsp">` here `../../` you have to configure it according to you project dir.